# DB2 field value replacement

Tags: sql, database, string, db2

I have a DB2 employee table with a column called "Name" - varchar. it is not a primary key. 'Space' is also considered valid value here. some fields under this column has just space.

Now I need a query that fetches all the values in this employee table by replacing 'Space' with NULL or any other default value say 'NoName'.

One idea I have got, is to truncate the values with LTRIM function in SELECT, which will result 'empty string' and if I could find some string operation function that returns NULL with 'empty string' as input, I can use IFNULL of COALESCE to replace the NULL with 'NoName' as a result.

But I could not recall any such function. Can you help?
Or is there any other way of accomplishing this ?

Comment: Simply `COALESCE(columnname, 'NoName')`?

Comment: Have a constraint that prevents zero length names. (And also <space> names.)

Comment: @jarlh coalesce wont 'remove' 'spaces' but only NULLs

Comment: @DDS, I know. But why allow space names? (See my second comment.)

Comment: @jarlh because those are already there according to OP

Comment: Then OP should fix that...

Comment: Maybe he has already many queries, not written by him, using those that can't be edited, we don't know. But it's OK to tell him, if he can, to  add constraints to remove those possibilities to reduce the 'error space'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, coalesce(nullif(name, ''), 'NoName') name_new
from table (values ' ', null, '', 'a') t(name);

NAME NAME_NEW
---- --------
     NoName
-    NoName
     NoName
a    a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
Select case when <your column> = ' '    -- replace spaces
              or <your column> is null  -- replace nulls
              or <your column> = ''     -- replace empty strings
       then 'no data'                   -- with string 'no data'
       else <your column>               -- if 'regular name' returns it
       end as '<your column>'           -- gives the column a meaningful title
from yourtable
```

when the column in 'space' or NULL or empty string it returns the string 'no data' otherweise it returns the actual value